# Yii record is not inserting into DB

Tags: database, activerecord, yii, frameworks

Below is my controller & model logic - I just started a barebones Yii installation to play around with it more.

I get no errors but don't see the new entry in the database - my db has been configured in the main.php (this works as Gii runs).

```
// controllers/PageController.php
class PageController extends Controller
{
    public function actionSave($value='')
    {
        $pageObj = new Page;
        $pageObj->savePage();
    }     
}


// models/Page.php
```

```
class Page extends CActiveRecord
{
/**
 * @return string the associated database table name
 */
public function tableName()
{
    return 'page';
}

/**
 * @return array validation rules for model attributes.
 */
public function rules()
{
    // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
    // will receive user inputs.
    return array(
        array('title, date_updated', 'required'),
        array('live', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
        array('user_id', 'length', 'max'=>10),
        array('title', 'length', 'max'=>100),
        array('content, date_published', 'safe'),
        // The following rule is used by search().
        // @todo Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
        array('id, user_id, live, title, content, date_updated, date_published', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
    );
}

/**
 * @return array relational rules.
 */
public function relations()
{
    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
    return array(
        'comments' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Comment', 'page_id'),
        'user' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'User', 'user_id'),
        'files' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'File', 'page_has_file(page_id, file_id)'),
    );
}

/**
 * @return array customized attribute labels (name=>label)
 */
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return array(
        'id' => 'ID',
        'user_id' => 'User',
        'live' => 'Live',
        'title' => 'Title',
        'content' => 'Content',
        'date_updated' => 'Date Updated',
        'date_published' => 'Date Published',
    );
}

/**
 * Retrieves a list of models based on the current search/filter conditions.
 *
 * Typical usecase:
 * - Initialize the model fields with values from filter form.
 * - Execute this method to get CActiveDataProvider instance which will filter
 * models according to data in model fields.
 * - Pass data provider to CGridView, CListView or any similar widget.
 *
 * @return CActiveDataProvider the data provider that can return the models
 * based on the search/filter conditions.
 */
public function search()
{
    // @todo Please modify the following code to remove attributes that should not be searched.

    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

    $criteria->compare('id',$this->id,true);
    $criteria->compare('user_id',$this->user_id,true);
    $criteria->compare('live',$this->live);
    $criteria->compare('title',$this->title,true);
    $criteria->compare('content',$this->content,true);
    $criteria->compare('date_updated',$this->date_updated,true);
    $criteria->compare('date_published',$this->date_published,true);

    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
    ));
}

/**
 * Returns the static model of the specified AR class.
 * Please note that you should have this exact method in all your CActiveRecord descendants!
 * @param string $className active record class name.
 * @return Page the static model class
 */
public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
{
    return parent::model($className);
}

public function savePage($value='')
{
    $page = new page;
    $model->isNewRecord = true;
    $model->primaryKey = NULL;
    $page->title='sample page';
    $page->content='content for the sample page';
    $page->save(false);
}
}
```

Comment: Could you please edit your post with your model's rules() method?

Comment: Why did someone downvote this & not even explain why??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Yii, when you want to insert into a table which has some null columns, you must put null columns in your rules as `SAFE` like below:

```
array('primaryKey','safe'),
```

Now, Yii knows that `primaryKey` is a null column. So, there would be no problem via inserting into the current model.

As a note, when you call save() method with FALSE, you are telling to your model to do not the validation on insert.

Also, the correct way to skip possible errors is to validate your model  before inserting like below:

```
if($model->validate()){
    // VALIDATE, YOU CAN CALL SAVE FUNCTION
}else{
    //here you can send an error message via FLASH or you can debug what the exact error is like below:
    CVarDumper::dump($model->getErrors(),5678,true);
    Yii::app()->end();
}
```

I hope, it help

Comment: gave you the answer cos you went over and beyond thanks mate really appreciate it

Comment: That CVarDumper() is awesome too! no more var_dump() or print_r() for me :)

Comment: You're welcome dear. Yii is really powerful and has a lot of tools to perform your jobs really easier than before.

Answer (score 1):

So simple... I hate Yii sometimes :-)

Had to set the save() to save(false)

```
    $page = new page;
    $page->isNewRecord = true;
    $page->primaryKey = NULL;
    $page->title='sample page';
    $page->content='content for the sample page';
    $page->save(false);
```

Comment: with false, you are telling the Yii to skip validation

Comment: If you modify your question with your model's rules() method, I'll describe you the right way

Comment: Ok.. i have added the entire model :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for that - I had missed out some columns.. (silly me)
Improve the function even further with the help above..

```
public function savePage()
{
    $page = new page;
    $page->isNewRecord = true;
    $page->primaryKey = NULL;
    $page->user_id = 1;
    $page->live = 0;
    $page->content='content for the sample page';
    $page->date_updated = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $page->date_published = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');        
    $page->title='sample page';

    if ($page->validate()) {
        $page->save();
    } else {
        CVarDumper::dump($page->getErrors(),5678,true);
        Yii::app()->end();          
    }
}
```